# WordPress Network for regional company websites

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping, iis

I am trying to setup a couple of company websites on a WordPress Network install running on IIS7 and SQL Server 2008.

Ultimately, the sites will work together like this:

Site 1 - All requests for this companies site (regardless of country/region) will go here. This site will just show a map to the customer allowing them to pick the regional site most suited to them (initially North America, Europe and Australia/NZ).

Site 2 - North American site

Site 3 - European site

Site 4 - Australia/NZ site

Sites 2-4 will share the same design and a lot of the same content. Where they will differ is in relation to news, contact information etc.

Ideally, the same user accounts would be able to make changes to all of the sites with the one login and post news to each of the different sites.

My current thinking to achieve this is to install WordPress at sites.domain.com and to then enable the Network feature (using sub-domains). Each regional site will then be region.sites.domain.com. Then, using a domain mapping plugin (recommendations? any IIS specific considerations?) I will redirect the regional domain names to the regional sub-domains I have created.

Does anyone have any recommendations for the best approach to this setup and any tips/tricks to make it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure that it would work with sub-sub-domains. :)

Most of your requirements (IIS aside) seem very manageable:

- consistent design would be easy to achieve with shared theme (or several child themes if required);
- users can be easily assigned to multiple sites, using single login and account (through editing site in Network Admin).

Comment: What would the issue be with the sub-domains? They are largely for internal use only. To the public, they would be shown as the regional domain (ie. domain.co.uk) and mapped by the WordPress plugin to the sub-domain

Comment: @anthon I am just not sure that two levels of sub is handled properly (natively at least), don't think I've seen such setup (I don't deal with multisite much).

Comment: if the main install(site1) is on `sites.domain.com` then it can handle the `region.sites.domain.com` structure with no problems.